# gnome shell with very high CPU usage

Tags: gnome, graphics, intel-graphics, opengl

i'm running ubuntu gnome 13.10 on my dell latiude e6510 with a i5 m560.
The I5 comes with a embedded Intel HD 3400 Graphics.

The average cpu usage of the `gnome-shell` is by 160% it's to high, I think.

Is there a problem with a driver?
If i call the command `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` it returns:

```
   OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
   OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.3, 128 bits)
   OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 9.2.1
   OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
   OpenGL extensions:
```

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,
i made a Bios Update. Now OpenGL is detected and the CPU usage is normal.

Comment: What did you update?

Comment: I've flashed the BIOS for my notebook.