# gnome-shell 3.26.1 constantly uses 20-30% CPU

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell

I upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10 on my **XPS13 9360** and have, as others, tons of issues. This one now is that the process

```
/usr/bin/gnome-shell
```

has a way **to high CPU usage of constantly between 20 and 30%**:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                     
2026 xxxxxx   20   0 4264020 703284 315308 S  29,6  4,3   9:32.37 gnome-shell
```

The used version is

```
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.26.1
```

This happens directly after booting the system with nothing open except a terminal running `htop` (beside some startup apps such as Dropbox) but clearly no heavy graphics programs.
I don't know where to start, here are some information about my graphics card

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)

$ glxinfo | grep -i render
direct rendering: Yes
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2) 
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap,
```

Please let me know what else I should post in order to trace this issues -- many thanks!

Comment: If your video card is relatively under powered gnome-shell uses llvm-pipe to use your cpu for 3d effects. You can try an alternate DE or google search to see if there is a solution for your graphics card or work around (you did not tell us much about your system or want is using your cpu).

Comment: Please post the output of `glxinfo | grep -i render`

Comment: I have hadded some info. I don't think I have any heavy graphics load, it happens right after booting. @Charles Green : done, thanks.

Comment: K - it appears that you are using the card for the 3D rendering (mentioned by  @panther)

Comment: Can you run top and determine what is using your cpu ?

Comment: @Panther: added above. this is, as written, the ``gnome-shell`` process.

Comment: You can file a bug report against gnome shell. If you google search there are a variety of suggestions, but I do not know what is most current with Ubuntu. https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/62522/gnome-shell-very-high-cpu-usage-on-a-clean-install-f21/ and https://askubuntu.com/questions/929903/gnome-shell-high-cpu-usage-and-huge-syslog and https://askubuntu.com/questions/369517/gnome-shell-with-very-high-cpu-usage

Comment: Thanks @Panther, I had already been looking at all these and also others, but I don't have any of these gnome extensions running and already use the video card for rendering...

Comment: I'm having the same problem (17.10, gnome-shell: 3.26.1) but I'm confused since my graphics card isn't terribly underpowered:
$ glxinfo | grep -i render
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 930M/PCIe/SSE2

Comment: @bb94, for me it turned out that the gnome-shell process went down to below 10% when turning off the system monitor https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/. Writing this as an answer now.

Comment: @ChristianStump That would be great if I didn't already have it off.

Comment: @bb94, I'm having the same issue with 20-30% gnome-shell CPU usage (with only terminal open), and I don't have any gnome extensions running.

Answer (score 12):

It turned out that the `gnome-shell` process went down to below 10% when turning off the system monitor extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/.

It also stays below 10% when increasing the refresh time to 1sec, while it went up again as soon as I moved it below 1sec.

Comment: TopIcons Plus was causing this for me on Fedora 30.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the same `gnome-shell` cpu hog issue and it was `kmailservice5` that fires up the cpu when you don't have Thunderbird. Whenever I click on a `mailto` link, the cpu goes crazy and so does `gnome-shell` and `kmailservice5` does nothing. It's a [reported KDE bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=354151) and has been fixed since but for other Ubuntu LTS like 16.10, the fix is to uninstall `kmailservice5`.